# Multiple permission request dialog not showing up after Android 13 update

Tags: android, permissions, dialog, android-permissions

I am requesting multiple permission (CAMERA, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and while doing that only 1 permission dialog is shown rather than 3 permission dialogs.

Here is the code snippet.

```
 private String[] PERMISSIONS;
   

  PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        };

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
             Manifest.permission.CAMERA) +ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) +ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mCameraView.start();
        } else    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                (this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                        (this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))  {
            ConfirmationDialogFragment
                    .newInstance(R.string.camera_permission_confirmation,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST,
                            R.string.camera_permission_not_granted)
                    .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);

        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
             
                if (!hasPermissions(MainActivity.this,PERMISSIONS)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,PERMISSIONS,PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        }


private boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... PERMISSIONS) {
        if (context != null && PERMISSIONS != null) {
            for (String permission: PERMISSIONS){
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean cameraPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean readExternalFile = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (cameraPermission && readExternalFile) {
                        // write your logic here
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.camera_permission_not_granted,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.gallary_permission_not_grated,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to request all three permissions but when one dialog opens up and the user accepts/rejects the permission, the permission dialog for the rest two permissions does not open up. And onRequestPermissionsResult is called multiple times and Toast message is printed on the screen as per the code.

Comment: Did you read the [granular media permissions behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)? `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` aren't permissions you can request anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [official document](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-11), starting with Android 11, the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission no longer grants any further access.

Hence, if you try to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` it always returns false internally. As a result, you'll have to bypass the permission check/request entirely.

Please review [Granular media permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions):

> If your app targets Android 13 or higher and needs to access media
> files that other apps have created, you must request one or more of
> the following granular media permissions instead of the
> READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission:

[image]

As an alternative you can also use [Photo picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. But even if I remove WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION, there are 2 more permissions (Camera and Read Storage) which I need to take simultaneously but 2 permissions popup are not getting shown. Can you help?

Comment: I am unable to get Camera Permission Popup or request dialog.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 13 the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has been replace by READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO.

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
```

And in your java file:

```
String[] permissions = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
};
```